# Syntax failure execution strored procedure by PDO statement (SQL Server)

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I have the following error :

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 102 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near '@IdIng'. in
>   **C:\Apache24\localhost\Class\IngredientsManager.php**
>   on line **64**

my related method in the class IngredientsManager.php is :

```
public function deleted(Ingredient $ingredient)
    {
        $db = parent::dbConnect();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL DeleteIngredient( @IdIng=:code)");
        $code='['.$ingredient->code().']';
        $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

I also tried :

```
public function deleted(Ingredient $ingredient)
        {
            $db = parent::dbConnect();
            $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL DeleteIngredient(?)");
            $code='['.$ingredient->code().']';
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $code, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

my related method from my class ingredient :

```
public function __construct(array $data)
    {
    $this->hydrate($data);
    }

    public function hydrate(array $data)
    {
        $keys = array_keys($data);
        if (array_key_exists(0, $keys)) {
            $this->setCode($data[$keys[0]]);
            $this->setCodealias($keys[0]);
        }
        if (array_key_exists(1, $keys)) {
            $this->setName($data[$keys[1]]);
            $this->setNamealias($keys[1]);
        }
        if (array_key_exists(2, $keys)) {
        $this->setSupplier($data[$keys[2]]);
        $this->setSupplieralias($keys[2]);
        }
        if (array_key_exists(2, $keys)) {
        $this->setEditdate($data[$keys[3]]);
        $this->setEditdatealias($keys[3]);
        }
    }
```

related code in controller :

```
case "deleteIgr":
        require("Class/Ingredient.php");
        require("Class/IngredientsManager.php");
        $data = array ('code'=> $_POST['code']);
        $deleterIngredient = new IngredientsManager;
        $deletedIngredient=$deleterIngredient->deleted(new Ingredient($data));
        echo 'ok';
```

I precise that my $_POST['code'] come by AJAX and it in a value code when I do color log and this values is passing, I don't know where come from this syntax error. This is the first time I have to use stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to execute your stored procedure with one of the following ways:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("{CALL DeleteIngredient(?)}");
$code = $ingredient->code();
$stmt->bindParam(1, $code);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $db->prepare("{CALL DeleteIngredient(:code)}");
$code = $ingredient->code();
$stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $db->prepare("EXEC DeleteIngredient @IdIng = :code");
$code = $ingredient->code();
$stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
$stmt->execute();
```

I can reproduce this error with PHP Driver for SQL Server and the reason is the missing `{}` around `CALL DeleteIngredient(?)`.

Comment: Look to work as it's execute BUT I don't know why is not deleting from the database :(

Comment: @SylvainMichel Try to remove `[]` around `$ingredient->code()` in `$code='['.$ingredient->code().']';`.

Comment: super it is working, you save my day, By curiosity, sql server don't take [values] but values ?

Comment: @SylvainMichel Symbols `[]` are used for database [identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017). You don't need to use them for column values.